# Setting click listeners on individual elements in a ViewFlipper widget

Tags: android, android-widget, viewflipper

I am building a collection Widget backed by a `ViewFlipper`, and ran into a snag when following the Android docs on [adding behavior to individual items](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#behavior).

I want to create two arrows which move the `ViewFlipper` to its previous and next views, as shown in this mockup:

[image]

In my `WidgetService`'s `getViewAt()` method, I have the following code to create a fill in intent:

```
final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(WidgetProvider.EXTRA_ID, mWidgetItems.get(position));
fillInIntent.putExtras(bundle);
remoteViews.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.btn_widget_next, fillInIntent);
remoteViews.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.btn_widget_previous, fillInIntent);
```

And then in my `WidgetProvider` I have this:

```
// Adding collection list item handler
final Intent onItemClick = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
onItemClick.setAction(NAVIGATE);
onItemClick.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, id)
onItemClick.setData(Uri.parse(onItemClick.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
final PendingIntent onClickPendingIntent = PendingIntent
  .getBroadcast(context, id, onItemClick,
     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_view_flipper, onClickPendingIntent);
```

What confuses me about the design here is whether or not I am supposed to be calling `setOnClickFillInIntent` on each button.  If I do set the intent on each button, I need a way of determining which button was clicked in my `WidgetProvider`'s `onUpdate` method (all I have now is the position of the view in the `ViewFlipper`).  I wasn't able to find an example of a Widget that uses click listeners for more than one action unfortunately.

Comment: Just wanted to give some feedback: the text you linked to says "Your RemoteViewsFactory must set a fill-in intent on each item in the collection.This makes it possible to distinguish the individual on-click action of a given item." So I think you can't set the fill-in-intent on the buttons (they are children of items), just on the items as such.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Thanks for taking a look, it seems like you're right from the docs.  I do have an example of a widget that uses a ViewFlipper with multiple buttons, however.  If only I could peak into their source code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to *is* a bit misleading with the following sentence:

> Your RemoteViewsFactory must set a fill-in intent on each item in the collection.This makes it possible to distinguish the individual on-click action of a given item

Well, you never really know until you try: it is possible after all to set fill-in-intents *on individual children* of the `RemoteViews` item. But you have to use a separate `Intent` for each of the buttons. I'll show how for the NEXT-button:

```
final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(WidgetProvider.EXTRA_ID, mWidgetItems.get(position));
bundle.putBoolean("FLIP_TO_NEXT", true);
fillInIntent.putExtras(bundle);
remoteViews.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.btn_widget_next, fillInIntent);
```

Then you have to check the `Intent` action (NAVIGATE) as well as the value of `intent.getBooleanExtra("FLIP_TO_NEXT", false)` in `onReceive()` and update the app widget accordingly. For example if "NEXT" was clicked:

```
ComponentName me = new ComponentName(this, ViewFlipperWidget.class);
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this); 
int appWidgetID = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
if (appWidgetID != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID)
{
     RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.view_flipper_widget);
     if (intent.getBooleanExtra("FLIP_TO_NEXT", false))
     {
          rv.showNext(R.id.viewFlipper);
     }
     else 
     {
          rv.showPrevious(R.id.viewFlipper);
     }
     appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetID, rv);
}
```